# MapKit returning 502 error

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I have an app where mapkit has been working fine. I ran it (without any changes) and on the debug console I get the message:

/SourceCache/GoogleMobileMaps_Sim/GoogleMobileMaps-263.5/googlenav/mac/Loader.mm:231 server returned error: 502

I tries it on a device and get the same result (different location, but same result).

The app displays the regular view, drops the annotation pin, pauses, then puts with the error and no map shows up. I checked lat and lng and they are valid values.

Basically, it was working an hour ago. Now, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely this was a service issue. Note other people reporting problem in the same time frame: [MKMapView Cannot Zoom Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094104/mkmapview-cannot-zoom-map)