# MKMapView Cannot Zoom Map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I created a really basic app that just shows an MKMapView and the UserLocation. I'm having problems drawing this base map sometimes (it only shows pieces of the map), and whenever I pinch zoom the map, it fails to redraw, and just shows the blank gray tiles. The console shows this whenever it needs to get a new map tile:

`/SourceCache/GoogleMobileMaps/GoogleMobileMaps-263.5/googlenav/mac/Loader.mm:231 server returned error: 502`

This looks like a gateway error, but that doesn't make any sense, since I'm using open WiFi for testing. I haven't implemented any region zooming code, I just want to display and zoom the basic map first. I'm using iOS 4.2.1 (8C148), so I'm wondering if this is a problem with the newer iOS versions? Any ideas?

Edit: Works fine now, must just be a problem with Google's servers.

Comment: Are you experiencing this problem both on the device and the simulator or only one of them?

Comment: Both. The above path is for the device, and on the simulator it is: /SourceCache/GoogleMobileMaps_Sim/GoogleMobileMaps-263.5/googlenav/mac/Loader.mm:231 server returned error: 502

Answer (score 0):

Just started getting the same error.  I've searched online and can't see anyone else having the issue (yet).  Thought it was something I did, but suspect its at Google's end.

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is solved now. It had to be a momentary Google Maps problem.

Comment: Yep, I was having this very problem about an hour ago, and when I came back from lunch just now it was cleared up.

Comment: Indeed, works fine now. Just bad timing when to test my app I guess.